# Navegação vertical do slider incluindo miniaturas de destaque

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

Existe um slider  [aqui neste site](http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/) que tem uma navegação vertical que se situa na lateral direita, que inclui as miniaturas dos slides anteriores e também dos slides seguintes. Eu gostaria de um **exemplo** para replicar este efeito e gostaria que esse exemplo utiliza-se **apenas** ***HTML, CSS e jQuery*** se possível.

Answer (score 6):

Fiz uma implementação que o galeria vai ter o mesmo tamanho do elemento a que ela pertence, se este elemento ocupar toda a tela, então a galeria irá ocupar toda a tela:

tentei evitar o uso de animações feitas em javaScript, para isto usei apenas CSS, deixando o JavaScript apenas com a missão de montar o CSS com as imagens (no caso uma URL em memoria) e fazer o controle do slide:

```js
var Galeria = function(gallery, indice) {  
  var self = this;
  self.indice = indice;
  self.gallery = gallery;
  self.container = gallery.parentNode;
  self.images = [].slice.call(gallery.querySelectorAll("[data-image]"));
  self.aside = document.createElement("aside");
  self.cssText = "";

  self.gallery.classList.add("gallery" + self.indice);
  [].forEach.call(this.images, function (image, indice) {
    self.buildCss(image, indice);
  });

  self.prevArrow = document.createElement("div");
  self.prevArrow.classList.add("prev-arrow");
  self.prevArrow.addEventListener("click", function () {
    self.changeImage(self.thumb.prox);
  });

  self.proxArrow = document.createElement("div");
  self.proxArrow.classList.add("prox-arrow");
  self.proxArrow.addEventListener("click", function () {
    self.changeImage(self.thumb.prev);
  });

  self.aside.appendChild(self.prevArrow);
  self.aside.appendChild(self.proxArrow);

  self.cssBlob = new Blob([self.cssText], { type: "text/css" });
  self.cssLink = document.createElement("link");
  self.cssLink.rel = "stylesheet" 
  self.cssLink.type = "text/css" 
  self.cssLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(self.cssBlob);
  self.cssLink.title = "gallery" + self.indice;
  
  document.head.appendChild(self.cssLink);
  self.container.appendChild(self.aside);

  window.setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(document.styleSheets);
  }, 1000)  ;
  
  self.thumbs = [].slice.call(self.aside.querySelectorAll("[data-thumb]"));
  self.interval = null;
  self.image = null;
  self.thumb = {};
  
  self.updateIndices();
}

Galeria.prototype.buildCss = function (image, indice) {
  var self = this;
  var classGallery = "gallery" + self.indice;
  var classImage = "image" + indice;
  var classThumb = "thumb" + indice;
  var thumb = document.createElement("div");
  self.aside.appendChild(thumb);

  self.cssText += "ul." + classGallery + " li." + classImage + " {\n" + 
    "\tbackground: url(" + image.dataset.image + ") no-repeat center center;\n" +
    "\tbackground-size: cover;\n" +
    "}\n" +
    "ul." + classGallery + " + aside div." + classThumb + " {\n" + 
    "\tbackground: url(" + image.dataset.image + ") no-repeat center center;\n" +
    "\tbackground-size: cover;\n" +
    "}\n";

  image.dataset.image = indice;
  image.classList.add(classImage);

  thumb.dataset.thumb = indice;
  thumb.classList.add(classThumb);
  thumb.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    self.changeImage(event.target);
  });
}

Galeria.prototype.changeImage = function (thumb) {    
  var self = this;
  self.gallery.dataset.inicial = thumb.dataset.thumb;
  self.updateIndices();
};

Galeria.prototype.filtro = function (colecao, prop, valor) {
  return colecao.filter(function (item, indice) { return item.dataset[prop] == valor; })[0];
};

Galeria.prototype.updateIndices = function () {
  var self = this;
  var atual = parseInt(self.gallery.dataset.inicial);
  var prev = atual >= 1 ? atual - 1 : self.thumbs.length + atual - 1;
  var prev2 = atual >= 2 ? atual - 2 : self.thumbs.length + atual - 2;
  var prox = atual < self.thumbs.length - 1 ? atual + 1 : atual - self.thumbs.length + 1;
  var prox2 = atual < self.thumbs.length - 2 ? atual + 2 : atual - self.thumbs.length + 2;

  if (self.image) {
    self.image.classList.remove("atual");    
    self.thumb.prev2.classList.remove("prev2");
    self.thumb.prev.classList.remove("prev");
    self.thumb.atual.classList.remove("atual");
    self.thumb.prox.classList.remove("prox");
    self.thumb.prox2.classList.remove("prox2");        
  }    

  
  self.image = self.filtro(self.images, "image", atual);
  self.thumb.prev2 = self.filtro(self.thumbs, "thumb", atual);
  self.thumb.prev = self.filtro(self.thumbs, "thumb", prev);
  self.thumb.atual = self.filtro(self.thumbs, "thumb", atual);
  self.thumb.prox = self.filtro(self.thumbs, "thumb", prox);
  self.thumb.prox2 = self.filtro(self.thumbs, "thumb", prox2);
  
  self.image.classList.add("atual");
  self.thumb.prev2.classList.add("prev2");
  self.thumb.prev.classList.add("prev");
  self.thumb.atual.classList.add("atual");
  self.thumb.prox.classList.add("prox");
  self.thumb.prox2.classList.add("prox2");
  self.autoLoop();
}

Galeria.prototype.autoLoop = function () {
  var self = this;
  if (self.interval) {
    window.clearInterval(self.interval);
  }
  var interval = parseInt(self.gallery.dataset.interval) * 1000;
  self.interval = window.setTimeout(function () {
    self.gallery.dataset.inicial = self.thumb.prox.dataset.thumb;
    self.updateIndices();
  }, interval);
};

var elementos = document.querySelectorAll("[data-gallery]");
var galerias = [].map.call(elementos, function (gallery, indice) {
  return new Galeria(gallery, indice);
});

console.log(galerias);
```

```css
html, body, header, section, aside, footer, div {
  box-sizing: border-box;    
}
html, body {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  min-height: 480px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}

section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

ul[data-gallery] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul[data-gallery] + aside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto 0px; 
  width: 64px;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2); 
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}

ul[data-gallery] + aside div {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;    
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: top, opacity;
}


ul[data-gallery] + aside div.prev2 {
  top: 0px;
}

ul[data-gallery] + aside div.prev {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 64px;
}

ul[data-gallery] + aside div.atual {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 128px;
}

ul[data-gallery] + aside div.prox {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 192px;
}

ul[data-gallery] + aside div.prox2 {
  top: 256px;
}

ul[data-gallery] + aside div.prev-arrow {
  background: url(http://cdn.flaticon.com/svg/66/66757.svg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0px;
}

ul[data-gallery] + aside div.prox-arrow {
  background: url(http://cdn.flaticon.com/svg/66/66783.svg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 256px;
}

ul[data-gallery] li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: opacity;
}

ul[data-gallery] li.atual {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Slider
</header>
<section>
  <ul data-gallery="" data-inicial="0" data-interval="5">
    <li data-image="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/red-lips-kreativ-portret-copy.jpg"></li>
    <li data-image="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/purple-portret-makiyazh-listya.jpg"></li>
    <li data-image="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/deadfall-ryzhevolosaya-palto.jpg"></li>
    <li data-image="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/devushka-model-portret-4724.jpg"></li>   
    <li data-image="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/portret-volosy-veter-gorod-copy.jpg"></li>
    <li data-image="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/passenger-vzglyad-otrazhenie.jpg"></li>
    <li data-image="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/moscow-venice-portret-volosy.jpg"></li>
    <li data-image="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/devushka-vzglyad-stil-1107.jpg"></li>
    <li data-image="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/devushka-model-makiyazh-1457.jpg"></li>
    <li data-image="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/dark-beauty-makiyazh.jpg"></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Caso haja a necessidade de possuir mais thumbs para a navegação, é possível adaptar o scripts para que o CSS dos mesmos também seja gerado automaticamente, e no caso não precisaria modificar muita coisa.

Comment: Modifiquei o script para ajudar a organizar o mesmo e criar um closure para a Galeria, agora é possível ter múltiplas galerias na pagina.

Answer (score 3):

Sem algum código fica difícil te ajudar 100%. Mas vamos lá:
Esse slider utiliza a mesma lista de imagens para os dois sliders (no slider principal não tem somente a imagem, mas tudo bem).
O que eu faria seria o seguinte:
Criaria div's com o tamanho da tela do usuário, colocaria o conteúdo e criaria as miniaturas em posição absoluta.
Com relação a javascript e jQuery em colocaria um setInterval para trocar o slide e as div's. Para a div eu usaria um transform: translate e para o mini slider eu usuaria um transform translate e scale ao mesmo tempo.
olhe o link do tableless: http://tableless.com.br/css-transforms/
Entenda que você não precisa de href para deslocar as div's e os mini sliders.

Uma exemplificação bem simples do que eu falei:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="slider-container">
      <div id="content-1"></div> 
      <div id="content-2"></div>
      <div id="content-3"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<nav id="mini-slider-container">
   <div id="arrow-up"></div>
   <ul id="mini-slider">
      <li id="element-1"></li>
      <li id="element-2"></li>
      <li id="element-3"></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="arrow-bottom"></div>
</nav>
```

observe que cada tanto o container de div's como o do mini slider possuem uma outra div dentro deles. O motivo é porque a div container e o nav mini-slider-container devem possuir tamanho fixo, no caso da div 100% da tela e do nav o tamanho que você quer que seja seu mini slider. A div de dentro terá um tamanho do número de elementos e espaçamento entre eles. Logo a div container e o nav mini-slider-container terão como css `overflow:hidden` para esconder os elementos que ultrapassam seu limite.

Com relação ao javascript:

```
var sliderContainer= document.getElementById('slider-container'),
    miniSlider = document.getElementById('mini-slider'),
    arrowUp = document.getElementById('arrow-up'),
    arrowBottom = document.getElementById('arrow-bottom'),
    sliderY = 0,
    sliderUnit = 1080,
    miniSliderUnit = 100,
    miniSliderY = 0,
    sliderMaxSize = 1080 * 3,
    miniSliderMaxSize = 150 * 3;

arrowUp.addEventListener('click', function(){
   if(sliderY >= sliderUnit){
      sliderY -= sliderUnit;

   }
   else{
      sliderY = sliderMaxSize;
   }
   if(miniSliderY >= miniSliderUnit){
      miniSliderY -= miniSliderUnit;

   }
  else{
     miniSliderY = miniSliderMaxSize;
  }
  sliderContainer.style.transform = 'translateY(' + sliderY + 'px)';
  miniSliderContainer.style.transform = 'translateY(' + miniSliderY + 'px)';
});
arrowBottom.addEventListener('click', function(){
   if(sliderY < sliderMaxSize){
      sliderY += sliderUnit;

   }
   else{
       sliderY = 0;
   }
   if(miniSliderY < miniSliderMaxSize){
      miniSliderY += miniSliderUnit;
   }
   else{
       miniSliderY = 0;
   }
   sliderContainer.style.transform = 'translateY(' + sliderY + 'px)';
   miniSliderContainer.style.transform = 'translateY(' + miniSliderY + 'px)';
});
```

O que eu fiz no código acima foi pegar as div's que conterão os elementos dos quer serão movimentados para fazer a função do slider (no caso sliderContainer e miniSlider ). Peguei os botões para click (arrowUp, arrowBottom ). A posição que está cada um dos sliders (sliderY , miniSliderY), a unidade de deslocamento (sliderUnit , miniSliderUnit) e o tamanho máximo (sliderMaxSize , miniSliderMaxSize) que podem atingir para poder retornar o slider para o primeiro elemento.

Após isso eu usei a lógica que eu falei, movimentei a div interna dos containers nos eventos de clique. A cada cliquei incrementei ou decrementei a unidade de deslocamento, salvei na posição de cada slider e apliquei o transform.

Acredito que esse código não esteja totalmente correto, pois responder como se faz um slider que nem o que você mostrou não é uma tarefa fácil de se fazer pois exigem vários conhecimentos específicos em conjunto. Mas eu acredito que eu tenha te passado uma idéia de como fazer.

Uma outra dica e ver se esse slider se adapta às suas necessidades: http://www.idangero.us/swiper/#.VX_6kvlVhBc

Answer (score 3):

Bom fiz um modelo que segue o mesmo desenho do site, ficou bem simples creio que esse seja a ideia deixar ele bem didático e comentando o código segue abaixo.

**obs:** usei as imagens da pagina que o AP postou, então qualquer semelhança é mera cópia do site mesmo.

```js
var t = {};
        t.arrayGlobal = new Array();
        t.sentido = 1;
        t.iniSlide = function(tamanho){
            $('.no_fit img').hide();
            for(var i=0; i<tamanho; i++){
                var obj = new Object();
                if(i===0){ obj.opcao = 'thmbNext2';}
                else if(i===1){ obj.opcao = 'thmbNext';}
                else if(i===2){ obj.opcao = 'thmbCurrent current-slide';}
                else if(i===3){ obj.opcao = 'thmbPrev';}
                else if(i===4){ obj.opcao = 'thmbPrev2';}
                else{ obj.opcao = ''; }                           
                t.arrayGlobal.push(obj);
                $('.slide'+i).addClass( obj.opcao );
            }
            t.slideAtualiza(1);
        };
        
        t.inverter=function(flag){
            $('.fs_slide_thmb').removeClass('thmbNext2 thmbNext thmbPrev2 thmbPrev thmbCurrent current-slide');
            var aux = new Array();
            
            if(flag===1){ //Up na lista                                
                for( var i=0; i<t.arrayGlobal.length; i++){
                    if(i + 1 == t.arrayGlobal.length){ aux.push( t.arrayGlobal[0] ); }            
                    else{ aux.push( t.arrayGlobal[i+1] ); }
                    
                    var obj = t.arrayGlobal[i];                    
                    if( obj.opcao != ''){                        
                        if(i + 1 >= t.arrayGlobal.length){
                            $('.slide0' ).addClass( obj.opcao );                              
                        }
                        else{
                            $('.slide'+ (i+1) ).addClass( obj.opcao );                           
                        }                                         
                    }                    
                }
            }
            else{ // Down na lista                  
                for( var i=0; i<t.arrayGlobal.length; i++){
                    if(i - 1 < 0){ aux.push( t.arrayGlobal[t.arrayGlobal.length-1] ); }            
                    else{ aux.push( t.arrayGlobal[i-1] ); }
                    
                    var obj = t.arrayGlobal[i];
                    if( obj.opcao != ''){                        
                        if( i - 1 < 0 ){
                            $('.slide'+(t.arrayGlobal.length-1) ).addClass( obj.opcao );                            
                        }
                        else{
                            $('.slide'+ (i-1) ).addClass( obj.opcao );                            
                        }                         
                    }                       
                }            
            }
            t.arrayGlobal = aux;
            console.log( t.arrayGlobal );
            t.slideAtualiza(flag);
            t.slideAtualiza(flag);
            t.slideAtualiza(flag);
        };
        
        t.slideAtualiza=function(flag){
            $('.no_fit img').hide();
            if( t.sentido != flag){ t.sentido = flag; t.inverter(flag); }
            $('.fs_slide_thmb').removeClass('thmbNext2 thmbNext thmbPrev2 thmbPrev thmbCurrent current-slide');
            var aux = new Array();
            
            if(flag===1){ //Up na lista                                
                for( var i=0; i<t.arrayGlobal.length; i++){
                    if(i + 1 == t.arrayGlobal.length){ aux.push( t.arrayGlobal[0] ); }            
                    else{ aux.push( t.arrayGlobal[i+1] ); }
                    
                    var obj = t.arrayGlobal[i];                    
                    if( obj.opcao == 'thmbCurrent current-slide'){ $('.no_fit .bg'+i).show(); }
                    if( obj.opcao != ''){
                        if(i + 1 >= t.arrayGlobal.length){
                            $('.slide0' ).addClass( obj.opcao );                               
                        }
                        else{
                            $('.slide'+ (i+1) ).addClass( obj.opcao );                           
                        }                                         
                    }                      
                }
            }
            else{ // Down na lista                  
                for( var i=0; i<t.arrayGlobal.length; i++){
                    if(i - 1 < 0){ aux.push( t.arrayGlobal[t.arrayGlobal.length-1] ); }            
                    else{ aux.push( t.arrayGlobal[i-1] ); }
                    
                    var obj = t.arrayGlobal[i];
                    if( obj.opcao == 'thmbCurrent current-slide'){ $('.no_fit .bg'+i).show(); }
                    if( obj.opcao != ''){                        
                        if( i - 1 < 0 ){
                            $('.slide'+(t.arrayGlobal.length-1) ).addClass( obj.opcao );                            
                        }
                        else{
                            $('.slide'+ (i-1) ).addClass( obj.opcao );                            
                        }                         
                    }         
                    
                }            
            }
            t.arrayGlobal = aux;            
        };
        
        t.iniSlide(6); // NUMERO DE IMAGENS QUE COLOCAR NO <UL>
```

```css
 #div-imagem{ width: 40%; height: 30%; }
    #div-controle{ float: right; }


.fs_thmb_wrapper {
    border-radius: 52px;
    height: 196px;
    width: 52px;
}
.fs_thmb_list li img {
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 0;
    transition: all 400ms ease 0s;
    width: 32px;    
}
.nav_button::before, .nav_button::after {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/themes/gt3-wp-goodwin/img/goodwin_sprite.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 32px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease 0s;
    width: 32px;
}
.nav-down::before {
    background-position: -32px 0;
}
.nav-down::after {
    background-position:  0 35px;
}
.nav_button {
    display: block;
    height: 32px;
    position: relative;
    width: 32px;
}
.fs_thmb_list li.thmbNext {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    top: 134px !important;
}

.fs_thmb_list li.thmbNext2 {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 196px;
    transform: scale(0, 0);
}

.fs_thmb_list li.thmbCurrent {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    top: 72px !important;
}

.fs_thmb_list li.thmbCurrent, .fs_thmb_list li.current-slide {
    left: -9px;
    margin-top: -7px;
    padding: 0;
}

.fs_thmb_list li.thmbPrev2 {
    opacity: 0;
    top: -52px;
    transform: scale(0, 0);
}

.fs_thmb_list li.thmbPrev {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    top: 10px !important;
}
.fs_thmb_list li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 52px;
    left: 0;
    list-style: outside none none;
    opacity: 0;
    /*padding: 10px;*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 72px;
    transition: all 300ms ease 0s;
    width: 52px;
}
.fs_thmb_viewport {
    display: block;
    height: 196px;
    margin-top: -101px;
    padding: 42px 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
    top: 50%;
    width: 52px;
    z-index: 44;
}
.fs_thmb_list {
    position: relative;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 20px 12px;
}
.fs_thmb_list li.thmbCurrent img, .fs_thmb_list li.current-slide img {
    display: block;
    height: 52px;
    width: 52px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="background: #aaa;">
    <div class="fs_gallery_wrapper fadeOnLoad" style="">
        <ul class="no_fit fs_gallery_container fade">
            
            <img src="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/headphones-405868.jpg" class="bg0">
            <img src="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Photo-2-12-15-15-37-14-copy-2.jpg"  class="bg1">            
            <img src="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/photo-1416339134316-0e91dc9ded92-copy.jpg"  class="bg2" style="background:url(http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/photo-1416339134316-0e91dc9ded92-copy.jpg) no-repeat;">
            <img src="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/joshua-tree-national-park-1593.jpg"  class="bg3" style="background:url(http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/joshua-tree-national-park-1593.jpg) no-repeat;">
            <img src="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/photo-1416339276121-ba1dfa199912-copy.jpg" class="bg4" style="background:url(http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/photo-1416339276121-ba1dfa199912-copy.jpg) no-repeat;">
            <img src="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/56MMSHQTR2.jpg" class="bg5" >
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="fs_thmb_viewport " style="width: 72px; opacity: 1;">
        <a class="fs_slider_prev nav_button nav-up" href="javascript:t.slideAtualiza(1)"></a>
        <div class="fs_thmb_wrapper">
            
            <ul style="width:560px;" class="fs_thmb_list paused">
                <li data-count="0" class="fs_slide_thmb slide0 ">
                    <img src="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/56MMSHQTR2-104x104.jpg" alt=" 0">
                </li>
                <li data-count="1" class="fs_slide_thmb slide1 ">
                    <img src="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/headphones-405868-104x104.jpg" alt="Euismod Molestie 1">
                </li>
                <li data-count="2" class="fs_slide_thmb slide2">
                    <img src="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Photo-2-12-15-15-37-14-copy-2-104x104.jpg" alt="Rhoncus Urna 2">
                </li>
                <li data-count="4" class="fs_slide_thmb slide3 ">
                    <img src="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/photo-1416339134316-0e91dc9ded92-copy-104x104.jpg" alt="Ornare Ultrices 4">
                </li><li data-count="5" class="fs_slide_thmb slide4 ">
                    <img src="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/joshua-tree-national-park-1593-104x104.jpg" alt="Condimentum 5">
                </li>
                <li data-count="6" class="fs_slide_thmb slide5 ">
                    <img src="http://www.gt3themes.com/wordpress-themes/goodwin/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/photo-1416339276121-ba1dfa199912-copy-104x104.jpg" alt="Placerat Ornare 6">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a class="fs_slider_next nav_button nav-down" href="javascript:t.slideAtualiza(0)"></a>
    </div>
  </body>
```